# Color detection in Camera (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, augmented-reality, detection

I am currently developing an interior design augmented reality application in Unity right now and I need to detect the color of the wall where the camera is being directed to but I can't seem to find a solution. Is there any function that will help me in my problem? Big thanks!

Comment: By camera, do you mean the physical one of your phone ? If your camera is "filming" an object, you want to know its colour, is it what you mean ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a raycast from the cameras position to a forward direction. See the code below as an example from Unity.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, 100.0f))
   {
        Color color = hit.transform.gameobject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
        print("Object colour: " + color);
   }

}
```

The RaycastHit variable holds information about any objects struck by the ray (invisible line between two points). You can refer to the objects colour by getting the material from the renderer component and then looking up its colour property from that. Something like:

```
Color color = hit.transform.gameobject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
```

*Now added to example above.
See the full syntax and possible parameters to use in the raycast here in the Unity docs => [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error "unityengine.raycasthit does not contain a definition for gameobject"

Comment: hit.transform.gameobject is the format I'll update the answer

Comment: This depends on how often you want to be testing the colour. So if you are always interested in what is ahead of the camera it should go in an update or fixedupdate function. If you only care when the user presses a button or key then put it in a public function to be called when you need it. The script should be on the camera gameobject

Comment: I added it in my main camera, update function but it seems that nothing is happening :/

Comment: So the example code states a ray will be cast 100.0f in front of the camera. If you remove this parameter the ray will be infinite. Once the ray hits a gameobject it should start printing output to the console if you included that part of the code example.

Comment: by gameobject you mean an object from unity? not from the real world that the camera gets?

Comment: My example is to get the colour of an object in Unity, if you need the camera of a real world object then @GuntherFox has given an answer which covers that. If when you use the GetPixel function you get the screen width and divide it by 2 you will have the absolute centre of the screen, same with the height.

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need to create a `WebCamTexture` object to begin pulling information from the device's camera.  [These Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-ctor.html) explain how to do so in the **Description** section of the class's constructor.

Once you've done that, you can use the [`GetPixel(x,y)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.GetPixel.html) function to get a color of a specific pixel.

Also, since there's likely to be imperfection in the image and the surface being looked at, I'd suggest taking multiple samples from the texture and averaging them together.

Comment: Hi, i am using kudan in developing my AR app and i dont know how to add a webcamtexture. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Sarah Oh!  If you're using Kudan I'd suggest their [Wiki on Getting Started](https://wiki.kudan.eu/Main_Page).  Go to that link, head into the links under "Unity Plugin", and by the time you get through to the [Taking a Screenshot](https://wiki.kudan.eu/Taking_a_Screenshot) part, you'll know everything you need to know to get a `Texture` from the camera and you can work with that.  You can then use that `Texture` instead of `WebCamTexture`

Comment: Thank you so much! @GuntherFox

Comment: Hi, what is the output of GetPixel? How would I know the value that I got from it?

Comment: @Sarah `GetPixel` returns a [`Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html).  That object will be a combination of a red, green, blue, and alpha value.